# (begginer) JSON deserialize to DataTable trouble

Tags: json, serialization, dataset

I'm begginer in JSON deserialize objects. I tried to use JSON.NET. 
I have a hardware device which send me a JSON message like this.

```
{
    "settings": [{
        "slotid": 13,
        "live": {
            "values": [
                {"id":1,"v":"3.5.0"},
                {"id":2,"v":""},
                {"id":3,"v":282827},
                {"id":4,"v":127},
                {"id":5,"v":127},
                {"id":10,"v":7},
                {"id":11,"v":1},
                {"id":12,"v":22},
                {"id":13,"v":1},
                {"id":14,"v":1},
                {"id":15,"v":0},        
                {"id":16,"v":2},
                {"id":17,"v":0},
                {"id":18,"v":0}
            ]
        },
        "presets": []
    }]
}
```

I tried to do it exactly as in

https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeDataSet.htm

but something goes wrong, I suppose that it depends of building of JSON answer format.

I used code like this:

```
 public class Product
  {
      public string settings {get; set;}
      public string values { get; set; }
      //public string presets { get; set; }
      public string slotid { get; set; }
  }
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string URL = "http://10.0.0.201/api/json/controls/get?slotid=13";
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URL);
        request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
        using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.UTF8);
            string json = reader.ReadToEnd();
            try
            {
                Product deserializedProduct = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Product>(json);

            }
            catch(Exception E)
            {

            }
        }
    }
```

In json variable I keep JSON message.

I suppose that I have to build custom datatable, but how?

Regards

Ps.

I forgot to say that I need to get only "id" and "v" from JSON from values.

Comment: Please specify what exact error you are getting, how do you know something wrong.

Comment: what exactly is the "something" you're referring to? Are you getting an error? I notice that in your code you've got `catch(Exception E)
            {

            }` which is potentially suppressing any exceptions. That's a code smell. If you're going to have a catch block, then you need to do something within it like log the exception. If you're not going to do that, then remove the try/catch, let your code fail and then you can see the exception and debug it.

Comment: Also, it would help if you would show us your `Product` class (and any child classes)...then we can see if the deserialisation is likely to succeed or not. P.S. You're not attempting to de-serialise to a DataTable at all, so it's unclear to me why you mentioned that in the question.

Comment: Hi guys, you're right, my question wasn't  precisious. So in excpetion I've this error "Exception e - $exception {"Error reading string. Unexpected token: StartArray. Path 'settings', line 1, position 13."} System.Exception {Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException}". I made this try/catch for stopping my app on error. My VS2k13 doesn't fail on error, if I will miss try/catch I will see Form.   ADyson, as you can see I tried to write my own class Product, it's at the begining of my code. From JSON string I need only id and v., I thougth that the best way will use DataTable